# Why RabbitMQ won't the connection stay open when not in use?

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp

I have used http://github.com/streadway/amqp package in my application in order to handle connections to a remote RabbitMQ server.  Everything is ok and works fine but when a connection is idle for a long period of time f.g 6 hours it gets closed. I check NotifyClose(make(chan *amqp.Error)) all time in my go routine and it returns :

> Exception (501) Reason: "write tcp
>   192.168.133.53:55424->192.168.134.34:5672: write: broken pipe"

1. Why this error happens? (is there any problem in my code?)
2. How long a connection can be idle?
3. How to prevent this problem?

Comment: "broken pipe" implies an underlying network problem causing the TCP connection to the RabbitMQ broker to be closed. There is insufficient information here to troubleshoot why that might occur; if the broker remains up at the far end after the error, this might imply an intermediate load balancer or stateful firewall device is terminating the connection, perhaps due to observing low traffic. AMQP & TCP have heartbeat mechanisms to help mitigate this, which you may wish to ensure are enabled. Not posted as an answer as there are numerous other circumstances which may contribute to this error.

Comment: If you can reproduce this, get a TCP traffic capture and post that to the [the `rabbitmq-users` mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users).

Answer (score 0):

As Cosmic Ossifrage says, the error is saying your RabbitMQ client has disconnected.

There are so many things that could sit between your client and server that can/will drop dormant connections that it's not worth focusing on how long your connection can be dormant for.  You want to set the requested heartbeat interval in your connection manager.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html

I'm not familiar with the framework you're using but I see it has a `defaultHeartbeat` field in *connection.go*.  You might need to experiment with the value to find the best balance is to stop the connection being killed but not hit the server too often with keep-alive traffic.

Comment: Related: [How to keep my connection alive for publishing messages with RabbitMQ streadway/amqp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68894836)