# How to keep my connection alive for publishing messages with RabbitMQ streadway/amqp?

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp

As connection opening each time for publishing is costly I'm trying to implement some way to keep the connection alive and share it in my app to publish messages.

```
var (
    Connection *amqp.Connection
    Channel *amqp.Channel
    err error
)

func Connect() {

    Connection, err = amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672")
    FailOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")

    Channel, err = Connection.Channel()
    FailOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
}

func CloseConnection() {
    err = Channel.Close()
    FailOnError(err, "Failed to close channel ")
    err = Connection.Close()
    FailOnError(err, "Failed to close connection ")
}

func KeepAlive() {

    queue, err := Channel.QueueDeclare(
        "hello", // name
        false,   // durable
        false,   // delete when unused
        false,   // exclusive
        false,   // no-wait
        nil,     // arguments
    )
    FailOnError(err, "couldn't publish tics")

    tic := "tic"
    for {
        err := Channel.Publish(
            "",         // exchange
            queue.Name, // routing key
            false,      // mandatory
            false,      // immediate
            amqp.Publishing {
                ContentType: "text/plain",
                Body:        []byte(tic),
                Expiration: "5000",
            })
        FailOnError(err, "couldn't publish tics")
        time.Sleep(5 *time.Second)
    }
}

func FailOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
    }
}
```

The function `KeepAlive` is an infinite loop that keeps sending a dummy message every 5 secs and that message have a TTL of 5 secs too so it gets destroyed.

```
func main() {
    rabbitmq.Connect()
    defer rabbitmq.CloseConnection()
    go func() {
        //publisher connection to stay alive as long as application is running
        rabbitmq.KeepAlive()
    }()

    data_layer.OpenDBConnection()
    router := gin.Default()

    router.POST("/whatever", whatever)

    err := router.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
}
```

Here I'm creating the connection and calling `KeepAlive` in a goroutine so it can work in the background, keeping my connection alive all the time.

My questions:

- I feel that this way is just a work around and although I've tried to search for examples how to keep it alive, it seems all of these examples are interested in the consumer side. Is there a cleaner way to keep my connection alive?
- Is keeping my connection alive as long as my application is running bad? performance wise (network, memory usage)? note: I'm planning to monitor this with Prometheus to watch the performance but any note about what I might face would be helpful

Side note: these tics that are sent will be sent to a dummy queue since if I send it to my queue that I consume messages from by another service it will get stuck behind actual messages that doesn't have TTL and these tics will grow very large.

Comment: My first question would be if you really need to do this. Is the few milliseconds delay caused by re-establishing connection on demand a significant issue for your application?

Comment: @Adrian probably yes because I will be receiving lots of transactions then publish it to RabbitMQ for notifications .....etc

We are expecting hundred of thousands of transactions at a later stage in the project

Comment: If you're getting that many transactions, it seems incredibly unlikely your connection would time out due to being idle; or that if the connection was dropped, any background routine checking it would manage to notice it dropped & reconnect before the actual producer needed a connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`streadway/amqp`](https://github.com/streadway/amqp) you don't need to implement the keepalive yourself. The library already provides this mechanism.

The method [`amqp.Dial`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/streadway/amqp#Dial) constructs a `Connection` with a default heartbeat of 10 seconds. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/master/connection.go#L140):

```
// connection.go
func Dial(url string) (*Connection, error) {
    return DialConfig(url, Config{
        Heartbeat: defaultHeartbeat,
        Locale:    defaultLocale,
    })
}
```

This works by sending [heartbeat frames](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html#heartbeats-interval) on the open connection, which is going to be more efficient and maintainable than sending fake messages to a queue created only for that reason.

From the above follows that you can change the connection heartbeat with [`amqp.DialConfig`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/streadway/amqp#DialConfig):

```
    conn, err := amqp.DialConfig(url, amqp.Config{
        Heartbeat: 5 * time.Second,
    })
```

What you might want to implement yourself is the reconnect-on-error logic. For that you can find some useful information here: [How to check if the channel is still working in streadway/amqp RabbitMQ client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108426)

Comment: yes this work pretty well, Although I've tried to implement the heartbeat. I think Instead of doing `Heartbeat: 5 * time.Second` 
I did `Hearteat: 5000` assuming it takes milliseconds as int

Thank you for your help @blackgreen 
and yes I will implement a reconnection logic

Comment: Heartbeat is of type `time.Duration`, thus 5000 is 5 microseconds. According to documentation when `Heartbeat` is lower than one second, library will use server value.